# YAML file to JSON conversion in LWC/Apex

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, js

Has anyone worked on this ?
I have YAML file uploaded as static resource.
Using either apex / JS in LWC, I need to convert it to JSON object.

Whole purpose is rendering data of YAML file on a LWC page. I am trying to read YAML at run time and show it's data.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? There are multiple JavaScript YAML parsers available.

Comment: Yes I am using JS library. But facing issue in loading YAML file from static resource.
I am seeking guidance there.
If anyone has already done it.
Also It'll be good if there is any standard function in apex

Comment: Please [edit] your post to show what you've tried and the specific problem you are encountering. Check out [ask] and [help/on-topic] to learn more about our format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a static resource, why not just put JSON data in? You could load that immediately into your component. Curious what the set up is that you would be storing data as a static resource if it changes frequently. Anyways, you can load and parse the YML file (or any static resource file really) using a standard module and [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch).

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import yaml from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/example';

export default class YamlReader extends LightningElement {

    async connectedCallback() {
        let resource = await fetch(yaml);
        let yml = await resource.text();
        console.log(yml);
        // do something with the yaml data
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually there are some RAML (Similar to YAML) files. RAML files has description of API's.It Will not change frequently. So going this way.

Its working.
Thank you nbrown,